# Delete Transient when clicking 'Save Changes' on options page

Tags: theme-options, api, options, transient

I have an options page setup for a ticker tape on a theme I am working on. It has a number of options such as Title, number of posts to display and what categories to display posts from.

I have also set it up using a transient cache option. Obviously I need to delete the transient key when any of the options are updated. I can set each of the options callback functions to delete the key ok. But what I am wondering can I write a function and add a filter so that when Save Changes is clicked the transient is deleted, so I won't need to code into each of the callback functions to delete the transient key.

Answer (score 0):

Right, jumped the gun again and just wasn't thinking.

You can delete the transient cache when sanitizing the options data.

When you create a function to sanitizing the options by adding in the code to delete the transient here, the transient is deleted when you click on save settings.